# I can't change my header(bootstrap or container) color

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of the header, color of the box in the middle (same as the color of header) and the background color, im new to html and css please help me with this i tried everything like finding the hex code of the color blue (#333580) and searching for it on the css, i was able to find it and replace with another color but nothing is changing.

[image]

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{


    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg") repeat top left;
    background-color:#333;

}
h1{
    font-size:45px;
}
h1 span{
    color:#ffa800;
}

a{
    color:#777;
}
a:hover{
    color:#222;
}
p{
    padding:5px 0px;
}
.header{
margin-left:-20px;
}
.wrapper{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto;
    min-height:550px;
    background: red;
    overflow:auto;

}
.wrapper_admin{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto;
    min-height:550px;
    background: red;
    overflow:auto;

}
.box{
    width:49%;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
a.back{
    color:#777;
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* Form Style */
.form_wrapper{
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:350px;
    font-size:16px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 7px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 7px #ccc;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 7px #ccc;
}
.form_wrapper h3{
    padding:40px 30px 20px 30px;
    background-color:#444;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.form_wrapper form{
    display:none;
    background:#fff;
}
.form_wrapper .column{
    width:47%;
    float:left;
}
form.active{
    display:block;
}
form.login{
    width:350px;
}
form.register{
    width:550px;
}
form.forgot_password{
    width:300px;
}
.form_wrapper a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777;
    font-size:12px;
}
.form_wrapper a:hover{
    color:#000;
}
.form_wrapper label{
    display:block;
    padding:10px 30px 0px 30px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.form_wrapper input[type="text"],
.form_wrapper input[type="password"]{
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 5px 30px 0px 30px;
    padding: 9px;
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    width:76%;
    background: 
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            left 25,
            from(#FFFFFF),
            color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE),
            to(#FFFFFF)
        );
    background: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(
            top,
            #FFFFFF,
            #EEEEEE 1px,
            #FFFFFF 25px
            );
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #f0f0f0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #f0f0f0;
}
.form_wrapper input[type="text"]:focus,
.form_wrapper input[type="password"]:focus{
    background:#feffef;
}
.form_wrapper .bottom{
    background-color:#444;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top:20px;
    clear:both;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.form_wrapper .bottom a{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    padding:10px 30px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#ffa800;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.form_wrapper a.forgot{
    float:right;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#ffa800;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.form_wrapper a.forgot:hover{
    color:#000;
}
.form_wrapper div.remember{
    float:left;
    width:140px;
    margin:20px 0px 20px 30px;
    font-size:11px;
}
.form_wrapper div.remember input{
    float:left;
    margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.form_wrapper span.error{

    color:red;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    display:block;
    margin:15px 30px;
}
.form_wrapper input[type="submit"] {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Myriad Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 0 9px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    margin:15px 20px 10px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff inset;
}
.form_wrapper input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #eaeaea inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #eaeaea inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #eaeaea inset;
    color: #222;
}
.clock{
float:Right;
margin-right:-80px;
}
.date{
float:left;
margin-right:50px;
margin-top:30px;
}

.trans{
background:transparent;
border:none;
font-size:17px;
font-family:Century Gothic;

}
.popup
{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0.9;
   top:0px;
   min-height:200px;
   height:100%;
   z-index: 100;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
/*    display:none; */

}
```

HTML LOGIN PAGE(index.php)

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/style.css" />
<html>      
<head>
<title>ABE E-Voting System</title>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">

    <a class="brand">

    <img src="ABE.jpg" width="135" height="60">
    </a>
    <a class="brand">
    <h2>E-Voting System</h2>
    <div class="chmsc_nav"><font size="4" color="white">CABANATUAN</font></div>
    </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Home.css" media="screen, projection" />

</body>
</html>
<div class="wrapper_admin">
</br>
</br>
</br>

<div id="element" class="hero-body-index">
<div id="loginform">
<p><font color="white"><h2>Login</h2></font></p>
<form action="loginprocess.php" method="POST" >
<table>
<tr><td><font color="white">Username<br>or USN:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="11" required></td></tr>
<tr><td><p><td></tr>
<tr><td><font color="white">Password:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type="Password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50" required></td></tr>
<tr><td><p><td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"><i class="icon-ok icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Login</button><p>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><font color="white" size=2>No account?<td><a href='register.php'><font size=2>Register!</a></font>
</td><tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<hr>
<footer>
<div class="foot_center"><p>Copyright &copy; 2018 ABE CABANATUAN
<br>
-------------Programmed by------------
<br>Jordan J. Santos - John Marlou Agulto</div>
</div>
</footer></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You have *vast* amounts of CSS that appears to be irrelevant in your question (so it isn't minimal), and absolutely no HTML (so it isn't complete).

Comment: Use the Web Inspector tools, by any web browser to change the colours yourself.

Comment: It it perhaps in the background image?

Comment: Why are people voting this down when he's clearly stated he's a beginner and needs help? Sometimes this site really annoys me. Jordan, please can you post the HTML structure of the page so we can reference the css.

Comment: @JohnBell thank you so much, you are the best person here. I posted the html.

Comment: Hi Jordan, this seems to be the HTML for the main page of your application - not the login page. Rather than copying the PHP code, just right click on the login page, and click "View Source", then copy the entire page of code and paste it into your edited question.

Comment: @JohnBell editted sir, its on the top thank you.

Comment: @JohnBell i can change the color using the chrome inspector and it works  well but when i tried to change it on the bootstrap css file nothing is changing.

Comment: @JordanJumaquioSantos after changing the css file, try refreshing the page by holding ctrl button, you might see the change

Comment: Which element are you changing? And are you changing the same selector in the css file?

Comment: omg that works well! thank you! @JohnBell